# Limitation Of inserting Image inside signature in different email clients?

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, tinymce, gmail, yahoo

GMAIL allows inserting image inside body from local system/public web server both but for inserting the image
inside signature it only allows the image from public web server not from local system.Is there any techincal limitation
in inserting the image inside signature from local system as gmail does not allow that?As per my understanding,
if GMAIL allows inserting image inside body from local system, it should allow for signature too?
For Information, here is the process to insert image in gmail signature. 
http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Add-An-Image-To-Your-Gmail-Signature.htm

Simlarly Yahoo does not allow insert the inserting the image in body anyhow. There is only one i figured it out we can do it on yahoo
i.e only on mozilla. Copy the image with CTRL+C and Then CTRL+V on Text Rich Editor. But chrome/IE does not seem to support that.

I am using tinymce as text rich editor for image signature. Is there a way i can upload upload from local system throw  any of these options

```
   1)Thrugh browsing to the director where image exist
    OR
   2)Drag/'drop
    OR
   3)CONTROL +C/CONTROL+V
```